# Does 'malloc_error_break' occurs on the same thread as the underlying memory corruption

Tags: ios, c, multithreading, crash, malloc

I am trying to debug an occasional crash in our iOS application.

We get 'malloc_error_break' with the usual 'object was modified after being freed'.
The crash occurs in the same C library, but at different malloc places.

The top of the backtrace looks like this:

```
* thread #29: tid = 0x3a03, 0x32c8cfa8 libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x32c8cfa8 libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break
    frame #1: 0x32c71ed0 libsystem_c.dylib`szone_error + 220
    frame #2: 0x32c71f1c libsystem_c.dylib`free_list_checksum_botch + 28
    frame #3: 0x32c1d3bc libsystem_c.dylib`tiny_malloc_from_free_list + 348
    frame #4: 0x32c1c44a libsystem_c.dylib`szone_malloc_should_clear + 1274
    frame #5: 0x32c1bf1e libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_zone_malloc + 66
```

Question:

Does this guarantee that the underlying memory corruption (f.i. double free, etc) happens on **the same thread** as the 'malloc_zone_malloc'? Or at least that the memory malloc_error_break is referring to, was allocated on the same thread?

Knowing this for sure, would help me isolate the crash from influence of other libraries, NSURLConnection requests, etc. The app is quite big and difficult too debug, as it is.

**Edit:**

I guess what I wanted too know first was something simpler.

Do different threads have separate heaps / malloc lists in iOS?

Comment: *Do different threads have separate heaps / malloc lists in iOS?* -- not heaps -- one list per core (at least, in the osx implementation).

Comment: I have tracked down the source of this idea: http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html . Although it refers only to Mac OS, but the blog states clearly that 'tiny' allocation lists are separate for different threads? Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

`malloc_error_break()` is invoked as soon as memory corruption is discovered, no matter what thread happens to discover it. There are absolutely no guarantees as to which thread this will be.

> Do different threads have separate heaps / malloc lists in iOS?

No. There is a single shared heap used by all threads in your process.

Comment: Please give more justification. In the meantime, I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: @lukasz the answer is correct +1. the system reuses certain allocations. it marks free allocations when they are returned (e.g. `free`d). when the reuse implementation accesses the allocations it vends, it may then perform integrity checks (not necessarily constantly exhaustive). in the case of a double free, the message/error occurs on the same thread. in the case of modification after free (your issue), the reuse implementation has no idea which thread wrote the freed memory -- it is telling you after the fact. guard malloc makes *most* of the errors in this class very easy to reproduce.

Comment: Added a simple answer to your simple question.